How to do fuzzy text search in PostgreSQL using multiple columns with GIN or GIST (against arbitrary unicode strings)?
A few questions related to properly indexing and querying words by prefix/suffix/contained in a fuzzy way.
Say I have this relevant words table, and referenced languages table:
CREATE TABLE languages (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    slug TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE words (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    language_id INTEGER REFERENCES languages(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    is_reversed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    is_phonetic BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);

The words.text is where the string of the word is stored. The is_reversed field is for if the word is reversed (for more optimal suffix searching), and is_phonetic is to tell if the word text is a phonetic string or literal word transcription string.
How can I create a series of indexes to allow for:

Optimal prefix searching of 1-2 characters.
Optimal suffix searching of 1-2 characters.
Optimal (fuzzy) prefix searching of 3+ characters.
Optimal (fuzzy) suffix searching of 3+ characters.
Optimal fuzzy "contains" searching of 3+ characters.
All of the above scoped to (language_id, text).
All of the above scoped to (language_id, is_reversed, text).
All of the above scoped to (language_id, is_phonetic, text).
All of the above scoped to (language_id, is_reversed, is_phonetic, text).

I am new to these more advanced features of PostgreSQL, but according to my findings, I need either GIN or GIST extensions, and custom indexes, perhaps like this?
-- Enable the pg_trgm extension for trigram-based searches
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

-- Create the languages table
CREATE TABLE languages (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    slug TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

-- Create the words table
CREATE TABLE words (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    language_id INTEGER REFERENCES languages(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    is_reversed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    is_phonetic BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);

-- Indexes for optimal searching

-- 1. Optimal prefix searching of 1-2 characters
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_prefix ON words (language_id, text) WHERE length(text) <= 2;

-- 2. Optimal suffix searching of 1-2 characters
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) <= 2;

-- 3. Optimal (fuzzy) prefix searching of 3+ characters
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_fuzzy_prefix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3;

-- 4. Optimal (fuzzy) suffix searching of 3+ characters
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_fuzzy_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3;

-- 5. Optimal fuzzy "contains" searching of 3+ characters
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_contains ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3;

-- Scoped indexes

-- 6. Scoped to (language_id, is_reversed, text)
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_prefix ON words (language_id, is_reversed, text) WHERE length(text) <= 2;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE language_id IS NOT NULL AND is_reversed IS TRUE AND length(text) <= 2;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_fuzzy_prefix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_reversed IS TRUE;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_fuzzy_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_reversed IS TRUE;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_contains ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_reversed IS TRUE;

-- 7. Scoped to (language_id, is_phonetic, text)
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_phonetic_prefix ON words (language_id, is_phonetic, text) WHERE length(text) <= 2;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_phonetic_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE language_id IS NOT NULL AND is_phonetic IS TRUE AND length(text) <= 2;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_phonetic_fuzzy_prefix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_phonetic IS TRUE;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_phonetic_fuzzy_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_phonetic IS TRUE;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_phonetic_contains ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_phonetic IS TRUE;

-- 8. Scoped to (language_id, is_reversed, is_phonetic, text)
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_phonetic_prefix ON words (language_id, is_reversed, is_phonetic, text) WHERE length(text) <= 2;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_phonetic_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE language_id IS NOT NULL AND is_reversed IS TRUE AND is_phonetic IS TRUE AND length(text) <= 2;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_phonetic_fuzzy_prefix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_reversed IS TRUE AND is_phonetic IS TRUE;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_phonetic_fuzzy_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_reversed IS TRUE AND is_phonetic IS TRUE;
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_reversed_phonetic_contains ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) >= 3 AND is_reversed IS TRUE AND is_phonetic IS TRUE;

Is that all correct?
Should I instead of:
-- 2. Optimal suffix searching of 1-2 characters
CREATE INDEX idx_words_language_suffix ON words USING gin (text gin_trgm_ops) WHERE length(text) <= 2;

...be just storing the reversed string, and do prefix searching, would that be better? (And is even #2 correct at all)?
Is generally the rest correct? Should I use any different columns in my table schemas?
Can I be using to_tsvector or to_tsquery to my advantage anywhere?
Is GIN the appropriate extension to use, or should I be trying GIST instead for these queries, or some other thing?
Theoretical examples of how these could be queried:
-- Enable the pg_trgm extension for similarity searches
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

-- 1. Optimal Prefix Searching of 1-2 Characters
-- Find words that start with 'ab' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND text LIKE 'ab%';

-- 2. Optimal Suffix Searching of 1-2 Characters
-- Find words that end with 'er' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND text LIKE '%er';

-- 3. Optimal (Fuzzy) Prefix Searching of 3+ Characters
-- Fuzzy search for words starting with 'con' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND similarity(text, 'con%') > 0.4; -- Adjust threshold as needed

-- 4. Optimal (Fuzzy) Suffix Searching of 3+ Characters
-- Fuzzy search for words ending with 'tion' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND similarity(text, '%tion') > 0.4; -- Adjust threshold as needed

-- 5. Optimal Fuzzy "Contains" Searching of 3+ Characters
-- Fuzzy search for words that contain 'gram' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND similarity(text, '%gram%') > 0.4; -- Adjust threshold as needed

-- 6. Scoped Queries to (language_id, is_reversed, text)
-- Find reversed words starting with 're' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND is_reversed = TRUE AND text LIKE 're%';

-- 7. Scoped Queries to (language_id, is_phonetic, text)
-- Find phonetic words that end with 'ing' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND is_phonetic = TRUE AND text LIKE '%ing';

-- 8. Scoped Queries to (language_id, is_reversed, is_phonetic, text)
-- Find reversed phonetic words that contain 'ph' for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND is_reversed = TRUE AND is_phonetic = TRUE AND similarity(text, '%ph%') > 0.4; -- Adjust threshold as needed

-- 9. Using Fuzzy Matching for Prefix and Suffix
-- Fuzzy search for words with a minimum length of 3 characters and starting with 'bio'
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND similarity(text, 'bio%') > 0.4; -- Adjust threshold as needed

-- Fuzzy search for words with a minimum length of 3 characters and ending with 'logy'
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND similarity(text, '%logy') > 0.4; -- Adjust threshold as needed

-- 10. Combining Multiple Criteria
-- Find phonetic words starting with 'tele' that are reversed for a specific language
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE language_id = 1 AND is_phonetic = TRUE AND is_reversed = TRUE AND similarity(text, 'tele%') > 0.4; -- Adjust threshold as needed

Is similarity enough (with GIN), or should that also be changed?
Note: I would like to do this against arbitrary languages/script (English, Arabic, Chinese, Hebrew, etc..), so not being limited to Latin/ASCII blocks would be really great.

This really seems like it needs more focus.  It seems more like a laundry list than a single question.  And some of the ideas seem somewhat ill-defined or nonsensical.  If you are restricting to strings with less than 3 characters, for example, than a 2 character "prefix" of it is not a prefix, it is the whole thing.  And what is a fuzzy prefix?  Is your example query for it doing the right thing, just too slowly?  Or is not finding what you want in the first place?
